# Kotlin's REPL println not printing to new line, instead prints everything to same line

Tags: kotlin, println

I'm using the Kotlin REPL from Intellij Idea.

When I type this:

```
println("line 1 ")
println("line 2 ")
 
print("same ")
print("line")
```

I expect this output:

```
"line 1 " 
"line 2 "
"same line"
```

But instead I get:

```
"line 1 line 2 same line"
```

**Why?**

[image: REPL console output]

Comment: I tried this in Intellij `2019.2.4` and I'm getting the expected result as output though

Comment: @MadhuBhat do you remember changing any setting? I'm using Open JDK 14.0.1

Comment: ah that might be the diff. I'm using oracle jdk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replicate this in my version of IntelliJ as well (2020.1.1). This seems to be a [pretty old bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14979) in IntelliJ. While it is listed on a backlog, I am not sure what that means in terms of priority for a fix.